# ANTLR v4 grammar fails to parse due to mismatched EOF

Tags: antlr4

Follows a simple grammar with ANTLR v4. This grammar when walked produces a error message
      **line 1:14 mismatched input '' expecting DimensionName*

for trivial input such as "sdarsfd integer" (without quotation marks).

SO has mention f similar errors and a bug perhaps were filed in 4.3 timeframe.
I have been using ANTLR 4.5.

Any help/pointer/solution?

```
/**
  A simple parser for a dimension declaration
*/
grammar Simple;
definition : dim;
dim : DimensionName DataType;

DimensionName : LETTER (LETTER)*; // greedy
DataType: 'integer' | 'decimal';
LETTER : [a-zA-Z];
DIGIT : [0-9];

WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to switch the two lexer rules `DataType` and `DimensionName`

```
...
DataType: 'integer' | 'decimal';
DimensionName : LETTER (LETTER)*; // greedy
...
```

As `DimensionName` matches every chars, 'integer' is typed as a `DimensionName` instead of a `DataType`. For "sdarsfd integer", the lexer produces two `DimensionName` token, so the `dim` rule cannot be matched. By switching the two lexer rules, the lexer produces a `DimensionName` token and a `DataType` token which match the `dim` rule.

Also, you can define `LETTER` and `DIGIT` as fragment:

```
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

Unless you want them to be matched as independent token (in your grammar, "a" will be typed as a `LETTER`).